# SD Card and an Amp

Tags: windows, sd-card

I have had some trouble with SD Cards, especially the formatting process. Nothing will format my card. But, I remembered hearing about if you place a hard drive next to an amp it will delete the data. Is this true about SD Cards? If so, will it remove data, or completely ruin the card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will do nothing.

SD cards, flash drives etc, are not sensitive to magnetism in the same way as hard drives.
You're also confusing the potential magnetic field around a loudspeaker with an amplifier, which doesn't have the same field.

Other than that, if an SD card ever starts misbehaving, just throw it away. They're not worth fighting once they start to fail.

Answer (score 0):

SD cards are more susceptible to time and usage more than they are being left next to random electronics.

Writing to SD cards is an inherently arduous process and puts a small amount of stress on the actual cells where data is stored. Erasing memory cells is actually slightly destructive and after anywhere from 10,000 to 100,000 (or less) writes the insulation in the cell will completely break down and it will be unable to hold any data.

Electrons may also leak from the trap over time and the data retention of NAND cells is of the order of years rather than decades. At higher temperatures data may decay faster.

Leaving them near amplifiers or speakers is likely to do a lot less damage than either of those processes. Actually *using* the card is the worst thing you can do to it.